One Time Pad and key randomness
The one time pad is considered perfectly secure under the condition that the key generation is truely random. In other words, if we consider a one bit key $k\in\{0,1\}$ :
\begin{equation}
P(K=k) =
\begin{cases}
p&,\text{if}\; k=0 \\
1-p&,\text{if}\; k=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
we must have $p=\frac{1}{2}$.
Perfect secureness can be formalized  by :
\begin{equation}
  P(E=e|M=m)= P(E=e)
  \end{equation}
that is to say the ciphertext $e$ probability does not depend on that of the plaintext message $m$, $e = m\oplus k$.
If we consider an eavesdropper able to listen the ciphertext, it means he would be
able to assess $P(E=e)$.
But in which way the fact that $p\ne 0.5$ would help him to gain information on the message $m$ ?
Computing $P(E=e)$ leads to :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(E=e)&= P[E=e,M=0,k=0]+P[E=e,M=0,k=1]\\
&\quad + P[E=e,M=1,k=0]+P[E=e,M=1,k=1]\\
&= P[E=e|(M=0,k=0)]P(M=0)P(k=0)\\
&\quad+ P[E=e|(M=0,k=0)]P(M=0)P(k=1) \\
&\quad\quad + P[E=e|(M=1,k=0)]P(M=1)P(k=0)\\
&\quad\quad\quad+ P[E=e|(M=1,k=1)]P(M=1)P(k=1)\\
&=\delta_{e=0}P(M=0)P(k=0)+\delta_{e=1}P(M=0)P(k=1) \\
&\quad + \delta_{e=1}P(M=1)P(k=0)+\delta_{e=0}P(M=1)P(k=1)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and finally :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(E=0)&= P(M=0)p+ P(M=1)(1-p)\\ 
P(E=1)&= P(M=0)(1-p)+ P(M=1)p
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The eavesdropper could listen a sequence of encrypted bits $e_{1},\dots, e_{n}$ and then estimate $P(E=0)$ and $P(E=1)$ as
\begin{equation}
e\in\{0,1\}\;,\quad P(E=e)\simeq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \delta_{e_{i},e} = p_{e}
\end{equation}
The goal of the eavesdropper would then be to assess $P(M=0)$ and $P(M=1)$ with
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
p_{0}&= P(M=0)p+ P(M=1)(1-p)\\ 
p_{1}&= P(M=0)(1-p)+ P(M=1)p
\end{split}
\end{equation}
One can check indeed that with $p=\frac{1}{2}$, probabilities $p_{0}$ and $p_{1}$ becomes independent of the these of the message.
Assuming $P(M=0) = u$, both previous equations become :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
p_{0}&= P(M=0)p+ P(M=1)(1-p)= up + (1-u)(1-p) = 1 + 2up -u -p\\
p_{1}&= P(M=0)(1-p)+ P(M=1)p=u(1-p) + (1-u)p = u + p - 2up
\end{split}
\end{equation}
But even if $p\neq \frac{1}{2}$, I do not think you can solve these two equations in terms of $(u,p)$ because both equations are in fact linearly equivalent.
So again, how an eavesdropper could benefit from a not truely random key generator ?

It's a little bit more complicated than that, as no TRNG produces an unbiased output.  $p$ is always $\frac{1}{2} \pm \epsilon$, yet OTPs still work.

Why do we fully need to solve an equation at all? If a ciphertext has just a tiny chance of being some value because of a plaintext value (or pattern) then there is already a leak of information. And as Paul indicates, OTP's work even if there is a minimal deviation from random; it's not a given that you might be practically learn anything from the plaintext even if the key stream has some correlation or similar. If you want to make your equations work then you'll need to inject the way that bits correlate.

You compute $p_0, p_1$ as they're interesting quantities to an eavesdropper, or that the eavesdropper would want to 'solve' for them. They're not, the quantity that's interesting to an eavesdropper is
$$P(M = m \mid E = e),$$
given that the eavesdropper has some prior on what $m$ could be.
When $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$, this quantity is no longer equal to the prior $P(M = m)$ for both $e = 0, 1$, and thus the probability the cleartext $m$ has some particular value can be estimated more closely than our prior by observing $e$ (which is precisely what the eavesdropper wants).

I don't think this is a practical attack, especially with a small bias. Even if the bias is large, one needs to calculate the threshold where the bias can be really helpful.
